# Building Ionic 4 Cordova Universal Windows App shows White Screen

Tags: uwp, angular6, ionic4, cordova6.4.0

I am attempting to build an Ionic 4 application with Cordova 6. The build is successfully using

```
ionic cordova run windows -- --arch"x64";
```

however the screen is always white. I tried to open up all the polyfills to see if that was the issue but no luck. 
I have also updated my config.xml file to add the following:

```
<platform name="windows">
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
<platform/>
```

When i try to open the .sln project into visual studio code 2017 i get tons of ignored icons on the files. 
Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the index.html file and replace the line:

```
<base href="/" />
```

With:

```
<base href="./" />
```

Comment: This gets me every time! Thanks.